# Where do I put this code in a DDD application?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design

in a DDD app I need code to do this

- Check IMemoryCache to see if it has a list of users
- If no users in cache
- Go get them from a REST API
- Add/update users from the API  into the    database    using efcore & repos

I need to use this code in the Web UI project and the web job background tasks project - my first thought was to use an application service, but not sure because I need to reuse it in the UI and the background task

Comment: Are users part of your domain model, or something separate?

Comment: They are part of the Domain model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this code refer to infrastructural features:

- Caching content
- API fetching
- DB access

These are not business features, so in a DDD application all this code go outside of the domain layer. The actual unit of code in which to implement these depends on the actual architecture of your application (which DDD is not).

In a classic layered application, DB access and API fetching usually go in the persistence layer. Content caching usually goes in the application layer. The dynamic around the DB vs API vs cache source of users sounds too confusing and edgy to give direction using other architecture styles.

Comment: I wonder then if just putting it in the repository would make sense. It's essentially just a way to get users but if they don't exist in cache, I need to go get them and update the cache & DB, but from a calling code perspective, it's just - get users

Comment: Applying single responsibility principle, you should have some unit acessing the users API, another managing cache data and a third for db access. The repository would probably be above as it's just below the domain layer/unit. I would also recommend wiring it all up using dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new REST API - getAndSaveUsers; busiess logic is in Service Layer.
This will internally invoke the (external API) getUsers REST API and also internally invokes the code (to save users to the DB) in repository layer.

So from your UI or any component, just invoke the new REST API - getAndSaveUsers